# Is there a R function which displays the frequency of each of unique occurrence in a specific column in a dataset?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

To keep it simple I created small dummy dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

myDF <- tibble(country = rep(c("UK", "US"), each = 3),
              date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01",
                       "2020-03-01", "2020-03-01"))
myDF <- myDF %>% mutate(date = as_date(date))

  country date      
  <chr>   <date>    
1 UK      2020-01-01
2 UK      2020-02-01
3 UK      2020-02-01
4 US      2020-03-01
5 US      2020-03-01
6 US      2020-03-01
```

I know the unique() function can be used to find that there are 3 unique values ("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01") in the date column.

```r
unique(myDF$date) # the unique values
length(unique(myDF$date)) # number of unique values
```

But how can I create a small table output which displays the frequency of each of these unique occurrences in a specific column (i.e. date) in my dataset? I am looking for something like this:

```r
   myDF$date  freq
"2020-01-01"     1
"2020-02-01"     2
"2020-03-01"     3
```

Comment: code for your example: myDF %>% count(date, name = 'freq')

Comment: myDF %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% ungroup()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can do something like 


  library(dplyr)
myDF %>% count(date, name = 'freq')
```